# Facebook Application using PHP on server problem

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying to wrtie a facebook application that generates random quotes using php. However, I'm getting this error and I don't know how to sort it.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/a9607557/public_html/index.php on line 8

This is the code I have:

```
<?php require_once 'includes/facebook.php';

$appapikey = '<Hash>'; 
$appsecret = '<Hash>; 
$facebook = new Facebook($appapikey, $appsecret); 
$user_id = $facebook->require_login(); 
$callbackurl = 'http://newuser.hostei.com/';

//initialize an array of quotes $quotes= array("Hello World.", "Yes", "New");

//Select a Random one. $i= rand(0, sizeof($quotes)-1);
```

I'm sure the problem must be lying in these lines of code.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Probably not that great that you are giving us your AppSecret and your AppAPIKey....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a quote:

```
$appsecret = '9ad606899a809cad1da38d12fc2101e0;
```

into

```
$appsecret = '9ad606899a809cad1da38d12fc2101e0';
```

May I suggest using an IDE that is good at detecting those problems. Like Netbeans?

Comment: Thanks but it is now giving me a different error 

FBML Error (line 8): illegal tag "body" under "fb:canvas"

:S not sure if this is from facebook, and if so how to change it

Comment: Your app is a FBML app, so it is already inside a body tag. Just imagine your app lives inside a big div. No head tag, body tag, and html tags allowed.

Answer (score 4):

Now that you've given away your application keys, you should regenerate them soon unless you want your app hacked.

Answer (score 2):

There's a missing ' at the end of the $appsecret line.